# deleteing the records in excel sheet before specific string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, xlwings

I have around 400+ records in excel. i wanna try to delete the records of before specific value records and want to delete again the records from that specific record to bottom records in excel file.
when i put the sample records in excel it's working fine. but when i using that original excel file  it's not working as expected.

let's suppose we have 10 rows and 4 columns in excel file. the 1st and 2nd row having different values like (JL,RF) in column, 3rd row has INS and 4th row also has INS type. The 5th,6th has different values(ED,JP). the 7th,8th,9th and 10th have the INS type value.

so before INS type rows we have to remove and again we have to delete the INS type values from 7th to 10th rows. in between the from INS rows to before INS records we need.

Here is my sample code :

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
groupin_df = df['content_name'].eq('rec_1').cumsum()
df[grouping_df.eq(1)].to_excel('file1_1.xlsx')
```

sample input :

```
   name      zip      content_name
1. jack     21340      JL
2. boris    12540      RF
3. smith    31245      INS
4. roy      41230      INS
5. rais     13240      ED
6. brad     10102      JP
7. surya    81023      INS
8. stones   62190      INS
9. Faizal   51231      INS
```

In input data frame, I want delete the content_name INS before specific records and again delete the records from where content_name is INS to bottom records.

output :

```
   name      zip      content_name
3. smith    31245      INS
4. roy      41230      INS
5. rais     13240      ED
6. brad     10102      JP
```

Comment: "I want delete the content_name record_2 before specific records" which specific records?

Comment: @Cam, let's suppose we have 10 rows and 4 columns in excel file. the 1st and 2nd row having different values like (JL,RF) in column, 3rd row has INS and 4th row also has INS type. The 5th,6th has different values(ED,JP). the 7th,8th,9th and 10th have the INS type value

Comment: so before INS type rows we have to remove and again we have to delete the INS type values from 7th to 10th rows. in between the from INS rows to before INS records we need.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to keep the rows between the first `record_2` (inclusive) and second `record_2` (exclusive).

Try this:

```py
s = df['content_name'].eq('record_2').cumsum()
df[s == 1]
```

Comment: it's not working as expected. it populating only one row.

Comment: Please give the non-working example. I might have misunderstood your question

Comment: let's suppose  we have 10 rows and 4 columns in excel file. the 1st and 2nd row having different values like (JL,RF) in column, 3rd row has INS  and 4th row also has INS type. The 5th,6th has different values(ED,JP). the 7th,8th,9th and 10th have the INS type value

Comment: so before INS type rows we have to remove and again we have to delete the INS type values from 7th to 10th rows. in between the from INS rows to before INS records we need.

Comment: Can you update the question with this info and indicate which row you want to keep?

Comment: @user98 I get that the result starts at `smith` because it's `INS`. But what rule says it stops at `brad`?

Comment: yes exactly what you said